# Why C++ associative containers predicate not transparent by default?

Tags: c++, containers, predicate, associative

Since C++14 we have `std::less<void>` that is transparent and more usefull in most cases, so is there reasons why, for example, `std::set` still has `std::less<Key>` as a predicate by default, not an `std::less<void>` except historical reasons.

Useful cases: `std::set<std::string>::find` with `std::string_view`, etc.

Comment: To not break backward compatibility in some subtle way, I assume.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would break current working code to do so.  Imagine I have

```
struct my_type
{
    int id;
    int bar;
};

namespace std {
    template<>
    struct less<my_type>
    {
        bool operator()(my_type const& lhs, my_type const& rhs)
        {
            return lhs.id < rhs.id; // bar doesn't need to be compared, only need unique id's in the container.
        }
    };
}

std::set<my_type> foo;
```

If `std::set` was changed to use `std::less<void>` then this code would no longer compile since `my_type` does not have an `operator <`.