# Why do I have to implement operator< when using operator() for sorting a std::set

Tags: c++, struct, set, compare

During a code review a colleage from mine was sorting a std::set using a struct. I am still quite new in C++ and had to implement it myself to fully understand it. Sadly I had some struggle because the MSVC forced me to implement operator< too after I implemented operator() of the struct.

Can someone explain me why it is necessary to implement both operator if I use a struct for sorting a std::set? I guessed that operator< is not needed because std::set calls some basic compare function?

```
class Hallo {
int one;
int two;
public:
Hallo(int one, int two);

bool operator < (const Hallo& rhs) const
{
    return one < rhs.GetOne();
}

struct cmpStruct{
bool operator()(Hallo const &lhs, Hallo const &rhs) const
{
        return lhs.GetOne() < rhs.GetOne();
}
```

---

```
int main(int ac, char* av[]){
const Hallo a{ 1, 1 };
const Hallo b{ 2, 2 };
const Hallo c{ 3, 3 };
const Hallo d{ 5, 5 };

std::set<Hallo, Hallo::cmpStruct> sortedList{};
std::set<Hallo> unsortedList{};

sortedList.insert(b);
sortedList.insert(c);
sortedList.insert(a);
sortedList.insert(d);

unsortedList.insert(b);
unsortedList.insert(c);
unsortedList.insert(a);
unsortedList.insert(d);
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54135237/why-c-associative-containers-predicate-not-transparent-by-default

Comment: Actually, you have some choices: 1) overload `operator<` for your `stuct`; 2) Write a free standing function for comparing `struct`s and pass it to `std::sort` or `std::set`; 3) Write a function object, that overloads `operator<` for comparing `struct`s.

Comment: Why is `std::set<Hallo> unsortedList{};` called `unsortedList`?  **All** sets are sorted.

Comment: Not sure what is asked here. If comparator is not provided for `set` (as in the second example) default `std::less` is called, which in turn will call operator less than (free standing or member) on the struct itself. This is why you have to provide such operator yourself in the second case.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews you missed one - specialization of `std::less`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can someone explain me why it is necessary to implement both operator if I use a struct for sorting a std::set?

Because you created 2 instances of `std::set` with `class Hallo` as a key and in the first you explicitly used `cmpStruct` as a functor, but in the second you implicitly use `std::less` as stated in [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set)

```
template<
    class Key,
    class Compare = std::less<Key>,
    class Allocator = std::allocator<Key>
> class set;
```

and `std::less` uses "some basic compare function" which is `operator<` [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/less):

> Function object for performing comparisons. Unless specialized, **invokes operator<** on type T.

emphasis is mine. So unless you specialize `std::less` for `class Hallo` or would not replace `std::less` in `std::set` instantiation with something else it would require `operator<` either as method or standalone function.

Comment: thanks for the help, this was the answer I was looking for. The compiler didnt let me implement the operator< with a '>' comparison. Is the reason for this because it is called by the method std::less and such an implementation wouldnt make sense?

Answer (score 2):

By default, `std::set` uses `operator <` to compare two `Hallo` instances.  This is why you would need to define an `operator<` function for comparing them.  There is no default operation for comparing `struct`s.

**Edit 1: Specifying an ordering or comparison function**
One of the `std::set` constructors allows you to specify a function for comparing `Hallo` instances.  If you don't want to add an overloaded `operator<` method to your struct, you'll need to pass a function that compares two `Hallo` instances, to the `std::set` constructor.  Again, there are no default comparison operators for `struct` or `class` instances; you'll have to create something.

**Edit 2:  Purpose of comparison function**
The comparison function argument of `std::set` allows you specify a comparison function for your `Hallo` structure.  It allows you to create one set that orders by member `one` and you could create another set that orders by the `two` member.

Also, you can define the ordering function for ascending or descending orders.  The choices are plentify.

Comment: C++20 will provide a nice way to make the class default comparable: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_comparisons

Comment: `std::set` does not use `operator<` your answer could be misleading.

Comment: @Slava:  How does `std::set` use comparison for integers?  I always thought it used the `<` operator.

Comment: It uses `std::less` which uses `operator<` by default. Your answer could be simplified but the problem that sometimes difference btw `std::less` and direct use of `operator<` is significant. Quote "If the function call operator of the specialization std::less<void> calls a built-in operator comparing pointers, **it yields a strict total order even if the built-in operator< does not**."

Answer (score 0):

The members of any mathematical set are unique; no two can have the same key.  But what does *the same* mean for a user-defined type like `struct`?  We know what it means for two strings to be equal, or two integers.  But the meaning of "same" for your struct is up to you, and up to you to define.

The members of `std::set` are both unique and sorted, by definition.  So, beyond enforcing uniqueness, `std::set` represents the members in order.  What order?  Again, for user-defined types, it's up to the user to define what it means for one object to be "less than" another.

That's where `operator<` comes in.  You define what it means for one of your objects to be less than the other.  `std::set` calls your user-defined operator on your user-defined type, and puts the members in the order thus defined.  It also uses that function to enforce uniqueness: If a new item cannot be inserted before an existing one nor after it, it's equal to it, and the insertion is rejected.